# Testing a large database query and mapping

Tags: hibernate, junit

I have a springboot application that takes in a post request, queries >20 tables for >100 fields using HQL and maps the fields back to objects.

Unfortunately lower environment database has no good data for these hundreds of fields so my question is thus:

How does one unit test such a large data structure without any data to test on?

Comment: Your question is a bit too vague. What kind of test you want to target first - syntax against real db, performance, unit tests of services using the data?

Comment: Unit tests of services using the data. In order to create unit tests I need to create an object populated with data in memory to test against, how should I go about doing that?

Comment: For unit testing services using data, mocking dao layer is a popular option. If you also need dao layer tests, h2 is an option (but beware of differences in supported features between db engines). Other option, which avoids h2 drawbacks, is launching the db engine you use in docker (via jUnit rules or similar mechanism)

Comment: Perhaps I don't understand, how do different kind of DB engines help me create data that does not exist?

Comment: We're not on the same page. If your problem is simply missing data, then get or generate the data.

Comment: Yes. My question is on how to generate the data.